# Coding with c: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exp10’

Tags: compiling

i don't understand how to compile this.

I've didnt put all of the functions that i've made in this library because all of them work properly, and it's the first time that i have to use math.h

Until now i've compiled like this without issues:

```
gcc -c -g f.c

gcc -c -g main.c

gcc -o main main.o f.o
```

I've tried to insert `-lm` but i don't get how and where it has to be putted.

//header

```
#include<math.h>
#define MAX 5

typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} bool;

typedef enum {ERROR=-1, OK=1} status;

status parse_int(char s[], int *val);
```

//function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"f.h"


status parse_int(char s[], int *val) {

    int l, val_convertito = 0, val_momentaneo = 0;
    for(l = 0; s[l] != '\0'; l++);
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            val_momentaneo = ((int) (s[i]-48)) * ((int)exp10((double)l--)); 
            val_convertito += val_momentaneo;
            *val = val_convertito;
        } else return ERROR;
    }

    return OK;
}
```

//main

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include"f.h"


int main() {

    int val_con, *val, ls;
    char s_int[ls];

    printf("Inserisci la lunghezza della stringa: ");
    scanf("%d", &ls);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Inserisci l'intero da convertire: \n");
    scanf("%s", s_int);

    val = &val_con;

    status F8 = parse_int(s_int, val);

    switch(F8) {
        case OK:  printf("Valore convertito %d\n", val_con);
                  break;
        case ERROR: printf("E' presente un carattere non numerico.\n");
                    break;
    }

}
```

Comment: As you issue is more with the code than Ubuntu, it would be best asked at: http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [exp10 manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man3/exp10.3.html):

```
SYNOPSIS
   #define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
   #include <math.h>

   Link with -lm.

CONFORMING TO
   These functions are GNU extensions.
```

Since these aren't standard functions, you not only need to have `#include <math.h>`, but you must have the line `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before the `#include <math.h>` line.

You also need to add `-lm` on the link line, so you'd have

```
gcc -o main main.o f.o -lm
```

The `-l` options normally come after all the `.o` files.

The easiest way to do all this is to use `make`. It already knows how to compile and link C files, so you just need to tell it which files depend on which other files, and change some variables to add customizations like `-g` and `-lm`.

Create a file named `Makefile` with these contents:

```
CFLAGS += -g
LDLIBS += -lm

main: main.o f.o

main.o: main.c f.h

f.o: f.c f.h
```

And then just type `make`:

```
$ make
cc -g   -c -o main.o main.c
cc -g   -c -o f.o f.c
cc   main.o f.o  -lm -o main
```